# ¿Cómo enviar el valor de un output al controlador?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, mvc, asp.net-core

De ante mano muchas gracias!

como le puedo enviar el valor que esta recibiendo un `output` por medio de un calculo en `javascript` hacia el controlador en `ASP.NET Core MVC`

**Codigo que uso en la vista HTML**

```
<label class="form-control" style="border:2px solid lightBlue">
                Calificación:<output class="form-control" style="margin:0 0 0 0.5rem" id="Nota">0</output>
            </label>
```

**Código que utilizo para calcular en JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
let SumasRespuesta=0;
let arreglo =[];
arreglo[0]= 0;
function promedio(Id){
    let vRespuesta = new Number(document.getElementById('Pregunta_'+Id).value);
    I=0;
    suma= 0;
    ResultadoPromedio=0;
    if (I=Id){
        arreglo[I]= vRespuesta;
    }
    for (let i1=1; i1<arreglo.length; i1++) {
        if (arreglo[i1]===undefined) {
            arreglo[i1]=4;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i<arreglo.length; i++) {
        suma += arreglo[i];
    }
    var dividendo= (new Number(arreglo.length)-1);
    ResultadoPromedio = (suma/dividendo);
    var PromedioTotal = ResultadoPromedio.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("Nota").value= PromedioTotal;
}
```

Comment: No es conveniente enviar datos que puedan modificarse en el navegador, lo mejor es volver a realizar validaciones y cálculos del lado del servidor.

Comment: tu me podrias indicar en donde puedo aprender esto, o en donde encuentro ejemplo para aprender? llevo muy poco como programador y si quisiera aprender un poco m'as de este tema! mil gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-data-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc/